# open HTML page from c#/asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

Is it possible from c#/asp.net to call/show a separeted html-page in the same window.

I don't want to store the entire html code into a 
, for exemple...
(that works).

Possible with javascript? or do I have to modify the code-behind?

The purpose is to load this html page everytime the default.aspx is invoked, as a webform(pop-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use `iframe` to open your `.html` page as:

`.aspx` Page:

```
<iframe id="ifrm" runat="server"></iframe>
```

And on `Page_Load`(code behind):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   ifrm.Attributes["src"] = "yourHtmlpageURL.html";
}
```

Comment: Is possible show this frame on a condition? for exemple if I have a method that checks if cookie are on the browser-client or not?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.You can test your condition and show/hide iframe accordingly.

Comment: The iframe looks really bad and it will open a new frame with scroll bar. Is possible to use another method instead of iframe? I would like that looks like a pop up. If I put the entire code into the aspx inside a container looks perfect but I don't know how to handle it to show it only under a condition if cookie are set or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use it asp.net

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

For c# application you can use WebBrowserControl.